# Xgboost crossvalidated model access

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost

Is there any way I can access the trained `xgboost` model from `xgboost.cv` directly? Or do I manually have to loop over the folds and perform a fit in this case?

```
xgb.cv(param, dtrain, num_round, nfold = 5, seed = 0,
       obj = logregobj, feval=evalerror)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cross-validate xgboost as you indicate:

`xgb.cv_m <- xgb.cv(param, dtrain, num_round, nfold = 5, seed = 0, obj = logregobj, feval=evalerror)`

Then, the number of rounds needed corresponds to the best AUC (the AUC train and test means and std resulted from cross-validation are saved in the data frame 'dt' - check out `names(xgb_cv_m)`):

`nr <- which(xgb_cv_m$dt$test.auc.mean == max(xgb_cv_m$dt$test.auc.mean))`

Next, when you fit the final model using 'xgboost' you use nrounds=nr

If you wish, you can also visually inspect the performance at every round by: `plot(xgb_cv_m$dt$test.auc.mean)`